# Does motherboard or processor or both decide the ram generation/type and frequency?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, chipset, ddr

As far as I know, the type and frequency of the memory supported by a computer depend on both the motherboard and the CPU plugged into the motherboard.
But I have seen this page of [Intel HM370](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/135101/mobile-intel-hm370-chipset.html) chipset and it has no mention of Memory type or frequency?

Does not the type and frequency of the memory depend on motherboard/chipset or incase of laptops it different as they are SoC??
Could someone clarify??

**Observation**: This [Intel® Desktop Board DQ87PG](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/70903/intel-desktop-board-dq87pg.html), speaks about the type and frequency of the memory as I would expect.

> Max Memory Size (dependent on memory type) - **32 GB**
> Memory Types                               - **DDR3 1333/1600**

Comment: The CPU specifies broad memory parameters, e.g. address size, data width, alignment restrictions, but it is the ***memory controller*** (whether implemented on motherboard chipset or on the CPU die) that dictates the supported memory types and clock frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is the CPU that determines the compatibility with the RAM in terms of frequency and maximum size. However, the motherboard's chipset (along with its CPU socket type) limits which CPUs can be used, and so indirectly it also effects compatibility with the RAM. Likewise, by limiting the number of RAM slots on the motherboard (usually as a cost or space saving measure), it's possible to prevent a system from ever reaching the maximum size of RAM supported by the CPU.

Using your Intel® Desktop Board DQ87PG as an example, it uses the Q87 Chipset. [This](https://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/Q87.html) is a list of processors compatible with that chipset. If you click on every compatible processor in that list, you'll see that every single one either supports DDR3 1333 or DDR 1600. By knowing which CPUs are compatible with their motherboard, a manufacturer is then able to build a list of potentially supported RAM speeds. Depending on the manufacturer, the specification for the motherboard may contain a note similar to the following: "The maximum memory frequency supported varies by processor"

Comment: Are you implying that motherboard has no limitation on the RAM speed itself, but only limit it by the socket it has? What about the AM4 socket where much newer generations of processor can be used on an old board? Does the board's chipset limit memory frequency?

Comment: Motherboard chipsets effect peripheral device and CPU support. 

For example, if you look at the table on the AMD website listing the difference between the AM4 chipsets, you'll see things like USB counts and speed, SATA ports, PCI express lane, and overclocking support: [link](https://www.amd.com/en/products/chipsets-am4).

Similarly, if you look at the AMD website for a specific chipset, it will show which generation/series of CPUs are supported: [link](https://www.amd.com/en/chipsets/x570).